# how to change value of javascript function in object

Tags: javascript, function, object

How to I change the value of onClick? I thought I could use object literals but doesn't work with functions

```
const button = {
 name: 'Car',
 onClick: function () {
 alert('You bought a Car')
 }
}

// Make the alert to show "You bought House"

// Make the button text to show "Bike"
button.name = 'Bike'
```

Without amending the button object itself

Comment: *"I thought I could use object literals but doesn't work with functions"* In what way? Using functions in object literals is **incredibly** common. It works just fine.

Comment: Why not? `button.onClick = function() { alert('You bought House')  }`

Comment: If your goal is to have the message show the value of the `name` property, use that property rather than a hardcoded value: `alert("You bought a " + button.name)`.

Comment: @Christiaan thanks, can you tell me why this won't work? button.onClick(() => alert('You bought House'))

Comment: Because you are calling the `onClick` function with a different function as argument. This is actually called a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function, refer to the current instance's `name` property instead of hardcoding `Car`:

```js
const button = {
  name: 'Car',
  onClick: function() {
    alert('You bought a ' + this.name);
  }
};

button.onClick();
button.name = 'Bike';
button.onClick();
```

If the `onClick` is invoked on the press of an actual button in the DOM, make sure to preserve the calling context, eg:

```
someHTMLButtonElement.addEventListener('click', () => button.onClick());;
```

If you can't change the `button` object, I guess you could reference a standalone `name` variable instead:

```js
const button = {
  onClick: function() {
    alert('You bought a ' + itemBought);
  }
};
let itemBought = 'Car';
button.onClick();
itemBought = 'Bike';
button.onClick();
```

Comment: without changing the actual object itself

Comment: button.onClick = function() { alert('You bought House')  } 

That works but could you tell me why this won't  button.onClick(() => alert('You bought House')) ?

Comment: In the second, you're invoking it and passing a parameter which is a function, rather than reassigning the `onClick` property. It'd work if you did `button.onClick = () => alert('You bought House');`